# Display variables using CBC MPS input in NEOS

Tags: variables, solver, neos-server, mps-format

Am trying to use NEOS to solve a linear program using MPS input.

The MPS file is fine, but apparently you need a "paramaters file" as well to tell the solver what to do (min/max etc.). However I can't find any information on this online anywhere.

So far I have got NEOS to solve a maximization problem and display the objective function. However I cannot get it to display the variables.

Does anyone know what code I should add to the paramters file to tell NEOS/CBC to display the resulting variables?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter file consists of a list of Cbc (standalone) commands in a file (one per line). The format of the commands is (quoting the [documentation](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/milp%3aCbc/MPS.html)):

```
One command per line (and no -)
abcd? gives list of possibilities, if only one + explanation
abcd?? adds explanation, if only one fuller help(LATER)
abcd without value (where expected) gives current value
abcd value or abcd = value sets value
```

The commands are the following:

```
?  dualT(olerance)  primalT(olerance)  inf(easibilityWeight)
integerT(olerance)  inc(rement)  allow(ableGap)  ratio(Gap)
fix(OnDj)  tighten(Factor)  log(Level)  slog(Level)
maxN(odes)  strong(Branching)  direction  error(sAllowed)
gomory(Cuts)  probing(Cuts)  knapsack(Cuts)  oddhole(Cuts)
clique(Cuts)  round(ingHeuristic)  cost(Strategy)  keepN(ames)
scaling  directory  solver  import
export  save(Model)  restore(Model)  presolve
initialS(olve)  branch(AndBound)  sol(ution)  max(imize)
min(imize)  time(Limit)  exit  stop
quit  -  stdin  unitTest
miplib  ver(sion)
```

To see the solution values, you should include the line `sol` - after the `min` or `max` line of your parameter file.

If this doesn't work you can submit the problem to NEOS in [AMPL](http://ampl.com/) format via [this page](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/milp%3aCbc/AMPL.html). In addition to model and data files, it accepts a commands file where you can use statements to solve the problem and display the solution, for example:

```
solve;
display _varname, _var;
```

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/R6g4oT6IdyI) describes how to convert MPS to AMPL.

Comment: I have included that line, however only the objective value is displayed, none of the individual variables are shown.

Comment: @user3043991 It seems that NEOS ignores the solution output printed by CBC. I've updated the answer with another way to get the solution using AMPL instead of MPS.